# Duplication and Save After Event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, duplicate

Is there a way when a product is duplicated so the 'Save After Event' is not fired or the product is not actually 'saved' until the product is 100% finished.
As the product is actually getting 'created' even though it's not finished. I'm trying to prevent this.

Thanks!

Comment: I decided just put some logic into the duplication_event first that removed the fields in quest, therfor the 'Save After' event wouldn't process what I need as it happens before the 'Save After' during duplication of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not a fan of rewriting major classes like `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`, one way to skip the Save After event is to first do a `<rewrite>` of the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class and then change `$_eventPrefix` property to anything other than `catalog_product`.

Something like this:

```
class My_Custom_Product_Class extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
   protected $_eventPrefix = 'custom_catalog_product';
}
```

Comment: Although this isn't the designed I used. The logic did work. Thanks.